# Need to find second to smallest and smallest values of arrays with a template

Tags: c++, templates

I already declared the lengths of the arrays inside of main, but since the user can input a small value for the first value of the array, I cant just assign the sort variables to be a[0]. It gives me the smallest value, but the second smallest value always returns the smallest value too.

```
template < class T >
T smalls(T *a, const int n)
{
    T small;
    T smallest;

    for (int i =0; i<n ; i++)
    {
        if (smallest > a[i])
        {
            small = smallest;
            smallest = a[i];
        }
            cout << "Smallest value of array: ";
            cout << smallest << endl;
            cout << "Second smallest value of array: ";
            cout << small << endl;
}
```

Comment: If the smallest value is repeated, is that also the second smallest value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never test small vs smallest. Try this.

```
if (small > a[i])
{
    small = a[i];
    if (small < smallest)
        std::swap(small,smallest);
}
```